# jquery Tablesorter - natural sort order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I've looked through all the answers listed for tablesorter but can't find what I'm looking for.

I have a table which I'm trying to sort, one column contains product model numbers which include both letters and numbers, the problem is that it sorts alphabetically but not with the numbers in their proper order.  For example the sorted column comes out like this:

STRB 18,
STRB 19,
STRB 2,
STRB 20,
STRB 23 - you get the idea.

I've gathered that I need this column to sort in natural order, but I've not got any js chops to do this with.  If anybody could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Comment: From what I've seen, this is called a "dictionary sort".

Comment: I wanted to add that I've added an alphanumeric sort to the [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) plugin in my github fork in case you were still interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery tablesorter plugin offers the ability to write your own parser.

Check out the example and give it a shot!

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had seen that but didn't know how to do it, you'll see by my above comments that I figured it out another way.  Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

taken from some old code of mine

```
compare = {
    natural: function(a, b) {
        function prepare(s) {
            var q = [];
            s.replace(/(\D)|(\d+)/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
                q.push($1 ? 1 : 2);
                q.push($1 ? $1.charCodeAt(0) : Number($2) + 1)
            });
            q.push(0);
            return q;
        }
        var aa = prepare(a), bb = prepare(b), i = 0;
        do {
            if(aa[i] != bb[i])
                return aa[i] - bb[i];
        } while(aa[i++] > 0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

example of use

```
test = ['img100b', 'img21', 'img18', 'img100a', 'img1', 'img2']
console.log(test.sort(compare.natural))
```

Comment: Was just getting ready to try this out when I figured it out using query_posts in wordpress, thanks for the effort though, much appreciated!!

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what you mean by "natrual" order, but I am guessing you mean that strb 2 would be before strb 18.

The order you have above is correct for strings.  if you want to sort by the number portion (assuming all the strb's are always the same) you will have to do a substring to get the number only and then sort the data.

I would also NOT do this in javascript.  Let your database work for you and let it handle the order of the data.  It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Limey,  I'd actually prefer to do this in php - this table will actually display in a WordPress site - any hint on how to go about this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you let the db do it?  If you wait till your php code, you are just adding extra processing time cause you DB will be able to sort faster than a custom PHP job.

Comment: This is where I found the "natural sort" term http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html - ended up query_posts came to my rescue in wordpress, didn't need to use js at all.